# Why use a Binary multiple in the Database DDL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I see every day a lot of DDL statemente where i work, and i have seen that the people use to us,.Binary Multiples , but when i ask why, nobody tell me a real reason.

i mean

```
   Create Table User(
      User_name Varchar2(64 Byte),
      User_comment (256 Byte),
      User_Description (1024 Byte)
      )
```

I see so often these values and i dont know why , if there is a logic behind that.

Comment: For some people, it's so ingrained that those just are the natural "round" numbers that they use everywhere.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so is just Personal/aesthetic, there ist not a reason of performance or something like that ?

Comment: Mostly just a habit. It may help to remember the size of columns in databases with lots of tables. Constraining yourself to a limited set of sizes helps to keep track of the sizes of variable length columns. It does not really matter if the description is 1000 or 1024 bytes long. Since we are computer nerds, we use the powers of 2 instead of the powers of 10 :)